# Oil drops running down over nylon threads

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Modelling a 1970's Rain Lamp, but stuck on realistic oil drops running down the threads. Any ideas appreciated.

Here is what I have so far using Blender's Particle system:
[image: 1970's rain lamp]

Note: Venus statue from Scan the World, Ferns from Blendswap.

Comment: What is your question? Please edit to make it clear what you want.

Comment: How might I realistically depict drops of oil running down a nylon thread?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: To get better help explain (or show images) of your settings and  please add an image that shows a reference of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I could only guess the problem is with drops of some liquid (probably oil) seen on the yellowish grille surroinding the statue. The drops there (if that's what is there) are too big and are too long; their material is a bit off probably too but that depends on kind of realism you're aiming.to. Anyway it's best to provide examples of your desired result and images of current setup as already stated.

Comment: [Here is what I am trying to achieve](http://imgur.com/a/N3XUE)